# Using rowspan in a forEach loop with ejs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, foreach, html-table, ejs

I have a bootstrap table that displays data from my mongoDB collection by looping through it. I'm trying to use `rowspan` on the last `td` of my table, called "Other", to span to the end of the table. But, because it's a loop it creates a nested `rowspan` and messes up the table. is there a way to make it so the rowspan doesn't nested like this? it needs to be in the `forEach` loop because the data is being pulled from my collection called environment, which can only be used in the `forEach` (if used outside of the loop it gives me the error "environment is not defined")

how it looks when I try to use rowspan on the last column:
[image]

html for table:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Code Version</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something->Membership</th>
      <th scope="col">SBMO</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">IVR</th>
      <th scope="col">CPM</th>
      <th scope="col">Other</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <!-- loop through each entry in mongoDB collection: environment -->
    <% environment.forEach(function(environment){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <%= environment.something %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.codeVersion %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.region %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.something %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.something %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.membership %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.SBMO %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.something %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.IVR %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.CPM %>
        </td>

<!-- this is the td that i'm having issues with -->
        <td rowspan=50 class="other">
          <%= environment.other %>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <% }); %> <!-- end loop through environment -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

inspector elements on `<td rowspan=10 class="other"><%= environment.other%></td>`:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the inspector elements on theses td that you're having issues with please ?

Comment: @JérômeW just added a screenshot

Comment: I added an answer, try it and tell me what is going on ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your td with `rowspan` after your `</tr>`, like following.

Instead of :

```
   <td rowspan=50 class="other">
       <div><%= environment.other %></div>
   </td>
</tr>

<% }); %> <!-- end loop through environment -->
```

Try this :

```
</tr>
   <td rowspan=50 class="other">
       <div><%= environment.other %></div>
   </td>

<% }); %> <!-- end loop through environment -->
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to make a difference because its still in the ejs forEach loop. If I take it out of the loop, I can't call ```environment.other``` because the variable ```environment``` is only available for use in the loop where it is called from the db

Comment: @Emily maybe you can find a way to get your "other" data out of the loop ? For example, if you can get it with `environment.other[0]` or something like that, after you can isolate your td with this data and not include it on your loop. I hope my explanations are clear to understand ^^